# How to remove "ubuntu" from boot options even after I deleted?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, windows, grub

I removed linux mint from my system, but still it would always boot to the GRUB thing. Then I followed a bunch of tutorials, and somehow made it so that when selecting "ubuntu", it still boots to windows. That's good, but now I just want to remove the "ubuntu" option so that I only can boot to windows. How do I do this?

For example i'll have:

Boot to ubuntu (which leads to windows 8)

Boot to Windows boot manager (which leads to windows 8)

Comment: If you no longer have Unix/Linux on computer, then isn't this question more for SuperUser? You don't have toolchain we use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not tried this but it seems like you could boot into a live linux then update your grub via `grub-mkconfig`. I believe it would "probe" the hard drives and only list the available OSs.

OR

Manually update your grub.cfg file so only the Windows entry is in it and set the time out to zero.

Yes the one that has `# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE` at the head.

BTW If you removed linux where does the grub.cfg file live?

Answer (score 0):

Being that you only have Windows, the only option now is to muck around with grub2win or something else that works with mbr/gbt and the grub format.

https://sourceforge.net/projects/grub2win/

or to put Linux on a memory stick and use the grub-* utilities and have them rewrite the mbr/gbt.